# div sitting about 50px below where it should be

Tags: html, css, punbb

Can someone tell me why my div `brdheader` isn't sitting at the top (the most top inside of, that is) of `punwrap`?

I'm using fluxbb, and the devtools in chrome aren't saying anything. There's no margin, or padding, so I have no idea what the problem could be.

This is the forum. Since I'm using FluxBB I can't exactly post all of the code.
http://flux.strange-coast.com/index.php

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: https://github.com/fluxbb/fluxbb, and for the CSS http://flux.strange-coast.com/style/BSTangram.css

Comment: what browser did you see the problem in?

Comment: Ah, I forgot to post this. Sorry! I seen it in Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have `margin: 30px 0px -10px 5px` on your `.pun h1` that's what's doing it. Adjust that to what you want

Comment: Ah, thank you very much! I'll accept as soon as I can. By the way, did you figure this out using something aside of Chrome? Cause Chrome wasn't showing me any margins at all on that part.

Comment: @CyanPrime Use Chrome dev tools, or Firefox dev tools, or Firebug (in Firefox), etc. Any of these will show you the margin on the `h1`.

Comment: I used chrome's dev tools console, I know what you mean, it wasn't showing anything on those two divs so I had to dig a little deeper. A lot of spacing issues have to do with `h1`, `h2`, etc. because the browser adds natural `margin` and `padding`, in this case the spacing was added manually

Answer (score 1):

Change your .pun h1 css line in your BSTangram.css on line 127 to the one below should fix it.

```
.pun h1 {
margin: 0px 0px -10px 5px;
margin-left: 5%;
padding: 0px;
}
```

As long as your going for this output, http://cl.ly/TGxf

If that's the case then there is your fix if not sorry I misunderstood.

Comment: Yeah glad to help, and if your using Chrome you can right click on the page and down at the bottom using inspect element you can navigate through the code and it shows the CSS to the right of it for each element.